# How to install imagemagick inside of electron app

Tags: imagemagick, electron

We have an electron app that uses Imagemagick on OSX, we have pre-installed that with brew install. It works fine in development, but when we package the app - it cant find imagemagick.

Can we brew install imagemagick before setting up the app? How would we go about doing this?

Comment: What error message do you get? What version of ImageMagick did you install. Perhaps electron does not work with IM 7, if you installed IM 7. Perhaps you have not provide the full path to IM convert/magick with your commands. Perhaps you need to put the path to Imagemagick into your PATH environment variable for electron?

Comment: We were using the CLI tools as part of imagemagick, but not a NPM module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) (which I recommend) you can simply add a `postinstall` script to your package.json to install Imagemagick

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "brew install imagemagick"
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to install it, or brew might not already be available on target machines, you can install imagemagick into a folder within the app then add that to the `extraResources` key of package.json

`"extraResources": ["imagemagick/"]`

This will tell electron-builder to bundle this folder into the archive. Then just reference imagmagick from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `/usr/local/bin` is not part of the path when electron builds the package.

I added it to my PATH in the script that uses imagemagick.

`process.env.PATH += ':/usr/local/bin';`

This still assumes the user has it installed on their computer.

Or you can specify the direct path.

```
const {identify} = require('imagemagick');
identify.path = '/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-11_2/bin/identify';
```

But identify relies on gs (Ghost Script) which in my case was also in `/usr/local/bin`. So I had to add that to my path anyway.

**Also, I came across this package which I have yet to try.**

https://github.com/joeherold/imagemagick-darwin-static

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

const graphicsmagick = require('graphicsmagick-static');
const imagemagick = require('imagemagick-darwin-static');

const {subClass} = require('gm');
let gm;

if (os.platform() == 'win32') {
    gm = subClass({
        appPath: path.join(graphicsmagick.path, '/')
    });
} else {
    gm = subClass({
        imageMagick: true,
        appPath: path.join(imagemagick.path, '/')
    });
}
```

Then you can call `identify` or `convert` as needed

```
    const getData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gm(filepath).identify({}, (err, features) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(features);
        });
    });
```